# Is it possible to have multiple validation errors with Sequelize custom validations?

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

```
  deliverableSchedule: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
    validate: {
      isIn: {
        args: ['onetime', 'recurrent'],
        msg: 'Must be one of "onetime", "recurrent"'
      },
      isRecurrent(value) {
        if (value === 'recurrent' && !this.recurrenceInterval) {
          throw new Error('recurrenceInterval must be set if deliverableSchedule is "recurrent"')
        }

        if (value === 'recurrent' && !(this.recurrenceCount > 0)) {
          throw new Error('recurrenceCount must be greater than 0')
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

That's my model definition. The problem is that I want both errors returned if the `deliverableSchedule` is `recurrent` and it's missing a `recurrenceInterval` and `recurrenceCount`

Comment: It doesn't make sense throwing two things at the same time, `throw` is like `return`, once it's called, the function returns, so only one error will be thrown when one of the conditions is true.

In your case, first of all `recurrenceInterval` is verified, if it isn't present, the first error will be trown, if later `recurrenceInterval` is present, the `recurrentCount` will be checked an will throw an error if 0 or less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Custom Error

```
class CustomError extends Error {

    constructor(message, errors) {

        super(message);

        this._errors = errors

    }

    get errors() {

        return this._errors;

    }

}

module.exports = CustomError;
```

and then

```
 var CustomError= require('./CustomError')


  deliverableSchedule: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
    validate: {
      isIn: {
        args: ['onetime', 'recurrent'],
        msg: 'Must be one of "onetime", "recurrent"'
      },
      isRecurrent(value) {
        var errroList = [];
        if (value === 'recurrent' && !this.recurrenceInterval) {
          errroList.push('recurrenceInterval must be set if deliverableSchedule is "recurrent"')
        }

        if (value === 'recurrent' && !(this.recurrenceCount > 0)) {
           errroList.push('recurrenceCount must be greater than 0')
        }

        if (errroList.length > 0) {
            throw new CustomError('Is recurrent error. See errors prop for error list', errroList);
        }
      }
    }
  },
```